# xypic and \mathcal math mod issue

Tags: math-mode, xy-pic

I'm curently trying to write a simple commutative diagram through xypic, which works on one of my files, but I can't make it work on a new one :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}

$$\xymatrix@!0 @R=2pc @C=3pc { \mathcal{E}_1 \ar[rr]&& \mathcal{E}_2}$$
\end{document}
```

LaTeX tells me `\mathcal` is not accepted out of math mode, but I can't add `$` inside xypic brackets and it does not seem that there is an equivalent of `mathcal` out of math mode. It seems to trigger an error because of the babel package, as it works well when i remove it. Still even putting xy package before or after, i get the error. Any hint on how to fix this?

Comment: Please always provide a test file that shows the error, not just a fragment. I completed your code to a minimal document, but I get no error, please edit to make it show the error, or show your log file so we can debug the error message

Comment: Oh sorry, it's part of a very long article, that's why.

Comment: Ok i got what make it not work (not how to solve it) I edit the post.

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine. Note that you should always use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$` ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/125871)).

Comment: The issue is with the Babel package, I edit the post to explain

Comment: You do not need to post a long original document, but you do need to post a complete document so that you can check that what you post is in fact an example of the problem (apparently it was not in this case if the issue is a conflict with babel which was not mentioned)

Comment: Yes, the error comes from a conflict btween xypic and \usepackage[french]{babel}

Comment: Do you really need `@!0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `!` to be a normal character, not a French punctuation shorthand

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}


\shorthandoff*{!}
$$\xymatrix@!0 @R=2pc @C=3pc { \mathcal{E}_1 \ar[rr]&& \mathcal{E}_2}$$
\shorthandon{!}

\end{document}
```

Note that in the original document the error message highlights the `!` it does *not* say that `\mathcal` is a problem. The error message is:

```
<xymatrix
! Xy-pic error: <addop> or <direction> or one of 1RCMLHW*! expected.
\xyerror@ ...#2}\fi \errmessage {Xy-pic error: #1}
                                                  }
l.8 $$\xymatrix@!
                 0 @R=2pc @C=3pc { \mathcal{E}_1 \ar[rr]&& \mathcal{E}_2}$$
?
```

The line break shows how far TeX had read, and it occurs immediately after `!` it has not yet seen the `\mathcal`

Comment: Why not `\shorthandoff{!}` inside `\[...\]` so `\shorthandon` is not needed (and `$$` is avoided)?

Comment: @egreg doing it out of the math seems more natural, apart from anything else it is needed if you try `align` rather than `\[`  I left the `$$`  rather than changing `\[` as it's bad style but not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In general, enclosing `\xymatrix` inside an `xy` environment is not needed, but with `babel-french` it might be the solution to your problems, because we can instruct LaTeX to disable the shorthand characters upon entering the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[cmtip]{xypic}

\AtBeginEnvironment{xy}{\shorthandoff{;:!?}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{xy}
\xymatrix@!0 @R=2pc @C=3pc { \mathcal{E}_1 \ar[rr]&& \mathcal{E}_2}
\end{xy}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, note that `$$` should never be used in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)